# Doctrine: How to insert foreign key value

Tags: symfony, insert, doctrine, foreign-keys, relationship

I have two tables in my database: `sliders` and `images`. One slider can have many images, so the structure of tables is:

```
 ---------      --------
| SLIDERS |    | IMAGES |
 ---------      --------
|   id    |    |   id   |
 ---------      --------
|  title  |    | title  |
 ---------      --------
               |  sid   |
                --------
SID is a foreign key associated to id in "SLIDERS" table.
```

In entities I put bidirectional relationships `OneToMany` and `ManyToOne`, so fetched Slider result would contain `Images Objects` that belong to him, and Images would contain `Slider Object` that belongs to them.

Sliders Entity:

```
class Sliders
{

...

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Images", mappedBy="slider")
 */
protected $images;
```

Images Entity:

```
class Images
{

...

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Sliders", inversedBy="images")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="sid", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $slider;
```

It is really comfortable for fetching. But now I can't understand how can I `INSERT` `sid` into `Images` table, since I don't have this field in my entity except `$slider` that returns Object. Is it possible to do it using this `$slider`?

Comment: You work on an objects, doctrine do the rest

Comment: So I have just cann `setSlider()` and put slider object as an argument and Doctrine will generate `sid` from it?

Comment: yeap, you work only on objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following function you should have already in your Slider entity (or similar).

```
public function addImage(Image $image)
{
    $image->setSlider($this); // This is the line you're probably looking for
    $this->images[] = $image;

    return $this;
}
```

What it does is if you persist the entity it writes the ID of the Slider (sid) into your Image.